# Make multiple files input with JSON Schema Form (Retool)

Tags: reactjs, json, multiple-file-upload, react-jsonschema-forms, retool

On **Retool**, I'm making **multiple files input** with **JSON Schema Form**, then, I tried the example of **multiple files input** from this website **[react-jsonschema-form](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/)** but the **multiple files input** doesn't take **multiple files**, it takes **only one file**:

[image]

This is the JSON Schema of the **multiple files input** from **[react-jsonschema-form](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/)**:

```json
{
  "title": "Files",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multiple files",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "data-url"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Are there anything wrong? or are there any ways to make multiple files input?

Answer (score 1):

I tested it using the link that is indicated in your question, everything works. Delete the comma after closing `properties`. In JSON, this is considered an error

```
{
  "title": "Files",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multiple files",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "data-url"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: After your suggestion, I tried the example on the website of react-jsonschema-form with both "Chrome" and "Firefox" removing the "comma" but it still takes only one file unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding files correctly? You need to hold down Ctrl and select files without releasing Ctrl ) Since your screenshot shows the inscription "Choose files", which indicates that multiple is enabled.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work even though clicking on "Choose Files" button holding "Ctrl". I tried again with both "Chrome" and "Firefox".

Comment: Now, I understand how to choose multiple files with the example. I used to choose one file with one click of "Choose Files" again and again. That's why I couldn't choose multiple files. To choose multiple files, I need to choose multiple files holding "Ctrl" with one click of "Choose Files".  Thanks.

Comment: @Kai Yeah, you can also select a range of files by holding down SHIFT and selecting the file you want to start with and the file you want to end with.

Comment: Yes, you right. However, I think it's not user-friendly and intuitive at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose multiple files with your **JSON Schema**:

```json
{
  "title": "Files",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multiple files",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "data-url"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

First, click on **"Choose Files"**:

[image]

Second, hold **"Ctrl"** or **"Shift"**, then, choose multiple files. *Don't release **"Ctrl"** or **"Shift"** until you finish choosing them. In the example below, I choose **"clover.jpg"**, **"rosemary.jpg"** and **"sunflower.jpg"**:

[image]

Finally, You can choose 3 files as listed under **"Choose Files"**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to choose multiple files with this **JSON Schema**:

```json
{
  "title": "Files",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multiple files",
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "file": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "File",
            "format": "data-url",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Click on **"＋"** to **add** single file input and **""** to **remove** single file input:

[image]